# Uploading a file via POST multipart/form-data from windows phone 8.1 Silverlight Httpclient to python server corrupts files

Tags: python, silverlight, post, file-upload, windows-phone-8.1

Originally, I was using Windows Phone 8 `System.Net.Http` library to upload an image from SD card to a Python server with the following code:

```
    private async void UploadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            // Make sure there is a picture selected
            if (photoStream != null)
            {
                // initialize the client
                // need to make sure the server accepts network IP-based
                // requests. 
                // ensure correct IP and correct port address
                var fileUploadUrl = @"http://IPAddress/";
                var client = new HttpClient();

                // Reset the photoStream position
                // If you don't reset the position, the content lenght
                // sent will be 0
                photoStream.Position = 0;

                // This is the postdata
                MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                content.Add(new StreamContent(photoStream), "fn", fileName);

                // upload the file sending the form info and ensure a result.
                // it will throw an exception if the service doesn't return 
                // a valid successful status code
                await client.PostAsync(fileUploadUrl, content)
                    .ContinueWith((postTask) =>
                    {
                        postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    });
            }

            // Disable the Upload button
            btnUpload.IsEnabled = false;

            // reset the image control
            DisplayImage.Source = null;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

In the server side, I used the following python code to decode the request:

```
ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers['content-type'])
data = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
```

It worked until I switched from Windows Phone 8 to Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight. Since the `System.Net.Http` library is no longer supported in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight, I used `Windows.Web.Http` instead with modification of the code:

```
    private async void UploadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            // Make sure there is a picture selected
            if (file != null)
            {
                // initialize the client
                // need to make sure the server accepts network IP-based
                // requests. 
                // ensure correct IP and correct port address
                var fileUploadUrl = new Uri(@"http://IPAddress/", UriKind.Absolute);
                var client = new HttpClient();

                HttpMultipartFormDataContent content = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();
                HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(photoStream);
                content.Add(streamContent, "fn", fileName);

                await client.PostAsync(fileUploadUrl, content);

            }

            // Disable the Upload button
            btnUpload.IsEnabled = false;

            // reset the image control
            DisplayImage.Source = null;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

The server side is unchanged. However, the resulting file uploaded now has extra bytes inserted periodically that look something like `'\r\n10000\r\n'` or `0D 0A 31 30 30 30 30 0D 0A`. The file also appears to begin and end with the same extra byte pattern. On the server `pdict` maps the boundary to something like `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`, but this seems to be the same behavior from when the file was uploaded via `System.Net.Http`. 
I tried removing these bytes by hand on a smaller file which seemed to confirm that the file is otherwise correct.

Why are these extra bytes present? Is this a problem with the Python server mishandling the POST request?

Comment: Microsoft released a portable version of the HttpClient available [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution when I encountered this issue:

Client:

```
 public async Task UploadImage(byte[] image, string url)
        {
            Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(image);
            HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(stream.AsInputStream());

            Uri resourceAddress = null;
            Uri.TryCreate(url.Trim(), UriKind.Absolute, out resourceAddress);
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Post, resourceAddress);
            request.Content = streamContent;

            var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request).AsTask(cts.Token);
        }
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    Stream requestStream = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await requestStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
        byteArray = ms.ToArray();
    }
    .
    .
    .
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```